# django form in bootstra modal not working

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a django form inside a bootstrap modal, it kind of works, Everything except the form shows up when i try to launch the modal.

**folder_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<<div class="modal fade" id="modal-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <main class="p-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
            <h1 class="myhead2">Create Folder</h1>
<hr>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form | crispy}}
    <input class="btn btn-dark my-3" value="Create Folder" type="submit" />
</form>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
            </div>
            
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
{% endblock %}
```

**home.html**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-1">Edit Contact</a>

{% include "ahmed_drive/folder/create" %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ahmed_drive/folder_form.html',
            type: 'POST',
            // headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            data: $('#modal').serialize(),
            
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#modal-1").modal("show");
            },
            
            success: function(data) {
                $('#modal-1 .modal-body').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I don't know ajax so i copied it from somewhere and modified it. please tell me whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

go like this...

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
```